# Can unplugging a device which is connected to a tapped fuse stop battery drainage?

Tags: battery, power, fuse, dashcam, drain

I have a dashcam installed in my car which gets power from the passenger side fuse box (using a fuse tap). Unfortunately, all of the fuses in the passenger side fuse box are all constant on so the dashcam is always on unless I turn it off or unplug the dashcam.

If I unplug the power cord from the dashcam, would that stop my battery from draining?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will stop the camera draining the battery, but that defeats the "convenience" of having it on - why not locate a fuse which comes on with the accessory position of the key..

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, thank you for the answer and suggestion. The fuse box which I'm tapping is on the passenger door side. The other two fuses box locations are under the hood and underneath the second row passenger seat. I'm not sure if I can route the power line from my dash cam to those other two locations easily. On the passenger side fuse box, there is one slot that days igniot, but that one is also constant on. I'm not interested so much I keeping my camera on when my car is parked. If it won't drain my battery while unplugged, then I am satisfied. Thank you!